# Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync doesn't work

Tags: office-js

In my app, I tried to remove the attributes I saved to office context store and reload. My code is as follows:

```
await Office.context.roamingSettings.remove('clientID');

await Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync();

await customAPI.logout();

setTimeout(() => {
  location.reload(true);
}, 1500);
```

Now in here, if I console log the value of `clientID` after the saveAsync and before the reload, it will say `undefined`. But when I reload and console log, it will show the past value. Any idea why this is happening?

This is a react app. I'm console logging the `clientID` in the app's `componentDidMount` function.

Comment: I'd appreciate the green tick if the solution has addressed your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm super surprised that this attempt doesn't resulted in some kind of react error.

To begin with, you shouldn't be able to use `await` keyword with `remove` method. That method is not an `async` method per documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_1/office.roamingsettings?view=office-js#saveasync-callback-

Now - the `saveAsync` method is, as the name suggests async. I strongly doubt that it's handled the way a regular async method is supposed to be handled through - like promises. So - below should work for you.

```
/* An awaitable remove and save functionality */
removeAsyncWithPromise: function(settingName) {
   return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      Office.context.roamingSettings.remove(settingName);
      Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(result => {
         console.log(result);
         if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
            return reject(result);
         }

         return resolve(result);
      });
 }); 
}
```

You will have to use `try / catch` around it when you're calling but you can use await with this.